# Allow/validate integer, decimal, float values in jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, floating-point, integer, decimal

I had a html field like below

```
<input type="text" name="price" class="validate_price" id="price"/>
```

So the field should accept only float, decimal, integer values from the input.

**jQuery code**

```
<script>
   function isFloat(value) 
             { 
                 return value!= "" && !isNaN(value) && Math.round(value) != value;
              }   
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.validate_price').focusout(function(){
             var value  = this.value;
             if (value)
                {
                   if (!isFloat(value) || !$.isNumeric(value))
                      alert('Value must be float or not');  
                }     

       });
   });
</script>
```

So from the above code, what all my intention is, I should allow user to enter integer values`(1,2,2, etc.,)`, float values`(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.2, 3.5, etc.)` and decimal values`(2.152, 4.56, 5.000, 6.3256, 2.00 etc.,)`

How to check/implement the above functionality ?

Comment: Please don't tag your question with a plugin that you're not using.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

If you notice from the [`jQuery.isNumeric()` manual](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isnumeric/) manual, it also validates floats, so there is no need to include any other arguments. To validate a number, all you have to do is use `jQuery.isNumeric()`:

```
if (!$.isNumeric(value)) {
    alert('Value must be numeric');
}
```

I made a quick jsFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/guxz9/

Answer (score 1):

Taken from a paragraph in [MDN documentation on parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat#A_stricter_parse_function) :

```
var filterFloat = function (value) {
    if(/^\-?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|Infinity)$/
      .test(value))
      return Number(value);
  return NaN;
}
```

Comment: Does this allows only float, decimal, integer values ?

Comment: If you'll remove the Infinity, then yes. Bear in mind it will still pass values that can be rounded to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

This will valid your all float numbers.It will also valid only single time negative sign('-') and dot(.) symbol.

```
function float_validation(event, value){
    if(event.which < 45 || event.which > 58 || event.which == 47 ) {
          return false;
            event.preventDefault();
        } // prevent if not number/dot

        if(event.which == 46 && value.indexOf('.') != -1) {
            return false;
            event.preventDefault();
        } // prevent if already dot

            if(event.which == 45 && value.indexOf('-') != -1) {
                return false;
            event.preventDefault();
        } // prevent if already dot

        if(event.which == 45 && value.length>0) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } // prevent if already -

    return true;

};


<input type="text" onkeypress="return float_validation(event, this.value)" class="form-control"/>
```

This will validate:
-12.33
12.44
12

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#Latitude, #Longitude, #Revenue").keydown(function(e) {
        debugger;
        var charCode = e.keyCode;
        if (charCode != 8) {
            alert($(this).val());
            if (!$.isNumeric($(this).val()+e.key)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

    return true;
    });
```